# Edit text without removing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide the text "33 available", the number changes as tickets are purchased. I am unable to edit the text directly.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="">
  <tbody>
   <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
     <td colspan="2">
        <input type="hidden" value="90" name="fees">
        <input type="hidden" value="1992261" name="feeID">
        <input type="hidden" value="Shirt,X-Small, Small, Medium, Large, X-Large, R" name="shirtSizeArray">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="setdiscountflag">
        <b>Runner</b>: $90.00<br>Run on the Upper Valley Haven's Covered Bridges Half Marathon team!<br>33 available
        <input type="hidden" value="Shirt,X-Small, Small, Medium, Large, X-Large, R" name="shirtsize1992261"><input type="hidden" value="" name="setGoalAmt">
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the following, but this will remove the other html info:

```
$('form#registrationForm table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr   td:contains("Run on the Upper")').html('<b>Runner:</b> $90.00<br />Run on the Uper Valley Haven\'s Covered Bridges Half Marathon team!');
```

I also tried using .text, what is the best way to select 33 available and hide only that line?

Here is a fiddle with the HTML in it http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/76ebL7ko/1/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td table tbody tr td` - are you serious? By the way, neither fiddle nor question's code contains form with ID `registrationForm`.

Comment: About question in general: wrap required text with `<span>` with specific class and hide this `<span>`. Something like `$('#registrationForm table tbody td:contains("Run on the Upper") .js-count').hide();`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76ebL7ko/2/).

Comment: When you select an ID in there is no need to include the type before it, because each ID should be unique on the page.

Comment: Are you unable to edit that HTML file? Not sure what edit restriction you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text in a tag, this will make manipulation alot easier,

```
$($('td br:last')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<span id="avail">');
```

then manipulate with `$('#avail')`

http://jsfiddle.net/76ebL7ko/3/

Answer (score 1):

One easy option is to surround the '33 available' with the `<span>` tag like so:

```
<span id='available'>33 available</span>
```

EDIT: You can do this with the following code:

```
$('td').contents().filter(function() 
{
    return this.nodeType==3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
}).last().wrap('<span id="available">');
```

This is getting the last text node that has non white space characters and wrapping it in a span.
Now you can access just that text and hide it:

```
$('#available').hide();
```